# Magento - get uploaded file name in form upload field

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, file-upload

I successfully create a module that upload file to the directory and save the path to the database.

My problem is that, when I tried to update the uploaded file, the form upload field and button don't display the name of the uploaded file. To make it short, the upload field value was empty, supposed to be it was populated coming from the database. Also if I tried to select another file and save it, the path was save on the database and the file was uploaded in the directory, however the problem was the old file was not deleted or updated.

I tried to view class `Varien_Data_Form_Element_File` and saw that it has

```
public function __construct($attributes=array()) 
{
    parent::__construct($attributes);
    $this->setType('file');
    $this->setExtType('file');
}
```

only this function. Unlike in the class `Varien_Data_Form_Element_Image` that has different functions that adds select box and input hidden fields.

#### Question:

1. How do I update the uploaded file?
2. How do I Delete the uploaded file?

This is my form fields

```
$fieldset->addField('title', 'text', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('pmadmin')->__('Matrix Title'),
    'class' => 'required-entry',
    'required' => true,
    'name' => 'title',
));

$fieldset->addField('file_path', 'file', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('pmadmin')->__('File'),
    'value'  => '',
    'class' => 'required-entry',
    'required' => true,
    'disabled' => false,
    'readonly' => true,
    'name' => 'file_path',

));

$fieldset->addField('short_description', 'text', array(
    'label' => Mage::helper('pmadmin')->__('Short Description'),
    'class' => 'required-entry',
    'required' => true,
    'name' => 'short_description',
));
```

#### Note:

I am able to successfully update other form fields and the file path from the records but not the file uploaded.

#### UPDATE:

Grid page:

[image]

Edit page:

[image]

Comment: you are adding the image or other file?

Comment: Yes, the other fields are added to the records. When try to update the record, these fields has the value coming from the database but the upload form field don't contain the file name or path from the database.

Comment: added the answer it is related to save function.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add else statment if the user is not uploading for the edit. `$postdata['file_path']['value']` this is created by Magento automatically.

```
if(isset($_FILES['file_path']['name']) && (file_exists($_FILES['file_path']['tmp_name']))) {
    // something ....
} else {
    $postdata['file_path'] = $postdata['file_path']['value'];
}
```

Comment: Where i have to put this code? In the controller or in the form.php file?

Comment: @SunnyRahevar controller

Answer (score 0):

Add bellow code in your upload action in controller file

```
if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

    if(isset($_FILES['file_path']['name']) && $_FILES['file_path']['name'] != '') {
        try {   
            $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('file_path');
            // Any extention would work
            //$uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('csv','jpeg','gif','png'));
            $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);
            $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

            $path = Mage::getBaseDir('var') . DS ;
            $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['file_path']['name'] );
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());        
            }

        //this way the name is saved in DB
        $data['file_path'] = $_FILES['file_path']['name'];
    }


    $model = Mage::getModel('pmadmin/uploadfile');      
    $model->setData($data)
        ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
    try {
        $model->save();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Abdul, I have no problem with saving the file path to the DB. My problem is during the update. On the Edit page, all the forms has values coming from the DB, they can be updated and saved, however, the Upload Field is empty on the Edit page. If I tried to browse file and save it, the records is updated and the file was uploaded in the directory but the old file was still there.